# Replace Mathematica icon in window title bar by an own icon

Tags: dialog-window

I like to run a mathematica program in a customized window,
so I would like to have my own icon left to the window title of my notebook window instead of the system icon.
i.e.:

```
CreateWindow[DocumentNotebook[{TextCell["example 1"]}], 
 WindowSize -> 400, WindowFrame -> "ModelessDialog", 
 WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "MinimizeBox"},
 WindowTitle -> "test window"]
```

How can I achieve this?
What does "DocumentIcon" does in the WindowFrameElements option?
Does it depend on WindowFrame type?
If not directly possible, is there a work around? maybe with "frameless" and the using a docked cell?
(But this is actually not really streight forward)